# Easylist inside adjustwidth

Tags: easylist, adjustwidth

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{easylist}
          \ListProperties(Hide=100,Progressive=1cm,
              Style1*=\textbullet,
              Style2*=$\ast$,
              Style3*=$\square$,
              Style4*=$\square$)
          & First thingy   
          && Second thingy  
          &&& Third thingy
          &&&& Fourth thingy  
    \end{easylist}
    \lipsum[1]   
\end{adjustwidth} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am using `adjustwidth` inside whole document because I need indentation of 2cm. But when I use `easylist` inside `adjustwidth` there is no progressive function.
Command `\begin{itemize} ; \end{itemize}` is working well inside `adjustwidth` but its too complicated because in a lot of occasions I need to jump from different bullet level, then is easier to use `easylist`.

[image]

Comment: `adjustwidth` relies on the standard LaTeX list making tools, while `easylist` deliberately uses a non-standard method. You can't nest `easylist` in `enumerate`, for instance; so you can't in `adjustwidth` as well.

Comment: @egreg Hi, thanks for answer. Is there any other option instead of `easylist` which is making easier to use multi level bullet and which is compatibile with adjustwidth? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `adjustwidth` environment is defined via `list` which internally uses the primitiva `\parshape`. On the other hand, `easylist` relies on the primitives `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`.

When concurrent nonzero `\parshape` and `\hangindent`–`\hangafter` declarations  are found when TeX is finishing a paragraph, the former wins, which is why you get left alignment for all items in the `easylist`.

Simply put: you can't directly nest `easylist` in an `adjustwidth` environment, like you can't in `enumerate` or `itemize`.

You may use a `minipage` (but no page break is allowed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{easylist}
          \ListProperties(Hide=100,Progressive=1cm,
              Style1*=\textbullet,
              Style2*=$\ast$,
              Style3*=$\square$,
              Style4*=$\square$)
          & First thingy
          && Second thingy
          &&& Third thingy
          &&&& Fourth thingy
    \end{easylist}\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}\par\prevdepth\tpd
    \lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With some effort, no `minipage` is necessary and page breaks are allowed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
 {\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
  \setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
  \dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
  \@parboxrestore
  \leftskip=\dimen@
  \prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
  \begin{easylist}}
 {\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
  \unvbox\Easylist@box\par\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{Easylist}
          \ListProperties(Hide=100,Progressive=1cm,
              Style1*=\textbullet,
              Style2*=$\ast$,
              Style3*=$\square$,
              Style4*=$\square$)
          & First thingy   
          && Second thingy  
          &&& Third thingy
          &&&& Fourth thingy  
    \end{Easylist}
    \lipsum[1]   
\end{adjustwidth} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make new command `Easylist`, or to modify current `easylist` which includes 
`\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{easylist}
          %%bullet level
    \end{easylist}\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}\par\prevdepth\tpd` so I can only type `\begin{Easylist} %%bullet \end{Easylist}`. I will define `Listproperties` in preamble

Comment: @Beginner I did better. `;-O`

Comment: @ereg you did it perfect, thank you very much. :)