# Problem with spacing after Easylist

Tags: spacing, easylist

Creator of macro `Easylist` is @ereg ([Easylist inside adjustwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442284/easylist-inside-adjustwidth/442294#442294))

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
{\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
\dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
\@parboxrestore
\leftskip=\dimen@
\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
\begin{easylist}}
{\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
\unvbox\Easylist@box\par\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed,
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm,
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm,
Style1*=\textbullet\hspace{0.25cm},%
Style2*=$\circ$\hspace{0.25cm},%
Style3*=\tiny$\blacksquare$\hspace{0.25cm},%
Style4*=\tiny$\square$\hspace{0.25cm})

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\section{Section1}
    \lipsum[1]
\section{Section2}
    \begin{Easylist}
        & 1
        & 2
        & 3
        & 4
        & 5
    \end{Easylist}
\section{Section3}
    \begin{Easylist}
        & 1
        & 2
        & 3
        & 4
        & 5
    \end{Easylist}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I define spacing after `easylist`?

Comment: How about adding a `\vspace` after your defined `Easylist`?

Comment: Thanks for help, but do you know is there any global solution, like to put in preamble and never repeat it again? :)

Comment: You define `Easylist`, change its definition and it is changed.

Comment: I dont know how to do it, one guy from this forum defined `Easylist`. :)

Comment: In the second half of its definition you could add `\medskip` or `\bigskip` after `\par` to get some more space after the list for example.

Comment: It's good practice to post a link to the answer or source you've taken it from. Also, you could provide the "author" of such a macro `;)`. See, e.g., https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7724/97512

Comment: @Skillmon thank you, that is good solution!

Comment: @nox thank you for suggestion, I will edit my post and in future will stick to this rule! :)

Comment: How about *not* using `easylist` that makes mote problems than it solves?

Comment: @egreg because `easylist` enables easy transition between different levels of buletts. Only problem in easylist is I dont know how to create new styles so I can easily switch from one to another https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442590/easy-list-creating-new-style/442602#442602. There is a way how to define new styles but I think you cannot modify margins, finalspace,etc.. I have modify stly with `\Listproperties` but it would be awesome if I know how to save it as new style, and just like that create few style in preamble so I can easy switch from one style to another.